Cohomology of a tubular neighbourhood
Fix $k<n$ and let $M$ a smooth compact oriented manifold with boundary of dimension $n$, embedded in some euclidean space. Let $V$ be an open tubular neighbourhood of $M$.
Is it true that the cohomology $H^k(V)$ is isomorphic to $H^k(M)$?
My attempt is that since $V$ is a tubular neighbourhood of $M$, then it deformation retracts onto $M$, but I am not sure since I do not know if I have to use the compact support cohomology since $V$ is an open manifold. Moreover I do not know if this is enough to conclude that $H^k(V)=H_c^k(V)$ and that this is isomorphic to $H^k(M)$ since $M$ is compact. Thank you.

Cohomology is homotopy invariant my friend and since the embedding of $M$ in $V$ is a homotopy equivalence we are done. This is simple to see for singular cohomology and it's a fundamental result of algebraic topology however I don't remember how complicated the proof is for de Rahm cohomology but it's still true in this case since de Rahm cohomology is isomorphic to singular cohomology tensored with real numbers.
It is also not enough to conclude that compactly supported cohomology is equal to standard cohomology of $V$ because imagine we have the manifold $M = [0,1] = I$ embeded in $V = I  \times (-1,1)$, $x \mapsto (x,0)$ then we see that the compactly supported cohomology of $V$ at 1 is equal to $\mathbb Z $ for singular cohomology or $\mathbb R$ if youre talking about de Rahm cohomology but of course standard cohomology is just zero since $V$ is contractible. If you want I can explain this in more detail

@Porcupine no it would be isomorphic to $H^k(V/ \partial V)$

de Rham ‍♂️‍♂️

@TedShifrin lol thanks

@Porcupine No look at some simple examples like $M = D^2$, then $V \simeq M$ (homotopy equivalent) and you can compute for yourself what happens if $k = 2$
